# Bounds of Visual Studio Code and AppleScript

Tags: visual-studio-code, applescript

How can I get to position and size of a window of the code editor Visual Studio Pro with AppleScript?

This is what I have tried:

```
tell application "Visual Studio Code" to get the bounds of window 1
--> error "Visual Studio Code got an error: Can’t get bounds of window 1." number -1728 from bounds of window 1

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Visual Studio Code"
        position of window 1
        size of window 1
    end tell
end tell
--> error "System Events got an error: Can’t get process \"Visual Studio Code\"." number -1728 from process "Visual Studio Code"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Visual Studio Code** does not have an **AppleScript** *dictionary file*, e.g.:

`${AppName}.app/Contents/Resources/${AppName}.sdef`

Therefore, scripting it with **AppleScript** will be limited.

**Visual Studio Code's** executable is:

`Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`

There are other apps that use **Electron** and one may have more then one app running that uses **Electron**, which can further complicate trying to use **AppleScript** with it.

That said, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get {position, size} of window 1 of process "Electron"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well. What is Code executable and how did you get that?

Comment: Do you know how to get the path? get path of window 1 of process "Electron" does not work

Answer (score 5):

You can use the process named "Code":

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Code"
    tell window 1
        set size to {1024, 768}
        set position to {100, 100}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This method works for me. I'm running VS Code 1.62.3 on an M1 Mac Pro running Big Sur 11.6. Calling the "Electron" process does NOT work on my system.